# Search engine behavior for asynchronous loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-crawler, googlebot

For a project I need asynchronous loading of HTML content using XMLHttpRequest or jQuery.

In concrete terms I make a request and load the HTML response into a div container.

(This is just some example code:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","testFile.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadXMLDoc()">

<div id="myDiv" style=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Now the question:** Afaik search engines don't see the content in `#myDiv`, am I right? What are my opportunities to make this content crawl able?

**Appendix:** The request may be also cross-domain!

Comment: Apologies for asking, indeed search engines would fail but not only them, but for JavaScript disabled browsers; Screen readers; Quality of Indexing.. etc. Why is it that you need to load this Client side?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I know of all these things. For this project, this is the requirement.

Comment: As Evgeniy has correctly suggested, Google 'look' for *"Hashbangs"* (#!) so it could be, `www.example.com/xml#!file=test` which you can use the `file` after the `hash` to decide which XML to get; for which google will collect a HTML Snapshot of the said URL. Secondly, it'll *have* to be JSONP if you want cross-domain, although that'll obviously only work if the domain is expecting your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evgeniy's answer is the best solution for something search engines are not designed to do, which is trawl dynamic pages.

You should clarify with your stakeholder whether the content actually needs to be loaded dynamically, or does it just need to be shown/hidden dynamically. If it's the latter, then you can include all the content in the original markup, then show/hide with css display:none, or jQuery toggle (same thing). If your content is bandwidth heavy like photos or videos, this may be a no go, but if it's just text, then text is cheap. Preloading and show/hide will let search engines trawl content and save you a heap of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Goog question!

As far as i know, [Ajax Crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=ru) can help you. But in needs serious update on server and client side.